# Data cleaning using subset with 2 conditions on same variable

Tags: r, subset, data-cleaning

I am a newbie to R,
I have at dataset ITEproduction_2014.2015 and I only want to see datapoints between 4 and 39 days. Currently I use 2 separate lines to create a subset.
Can I do this in 1 line? something like Data.Difference >3 and < 40?

```
 ITEproduction_2014.2015 <- subset(ITEproduction_2014.2015,Date.Difference>3)
 ITEproduction_2014.2015 <- subset(ITEproduction_2014.2015,Date.Difference<40)
```

thanks in advance,
Dirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a little googling would have solved your problem, for example read [this](http://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html) about logical operators,

like this?

```
ITEproduction_2014.2015<-subset(ITEproduction_2014.2015,Date.Difference>3 & Date.Difference<40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using subset altogether if you can. See the warning in the help file:

```
?subset()
```

If you like the syntax of `subset()`, and prefer it to standard subsetting functions like `[`, you can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
ITEproduction_2014.2015 %>%
    dplyr::filter(
    Date.Difference > 3,
    Date.Difference < 40
)
```